# Advice needed for refactoring legacy code

Tags: java, code-cleanup, legacy-code

I'm working a legacy code base and I would to use TDD to add new features to the code that I'm currently changing.

Please note that the current code base does NOT have any UT'S.

I have a `Calculator` class with the following implementation:

```
public final class Calculator extends CalculatorBase {
    public Calculator(Document document) throws Exception {
        super(document);
    }

    public int Multiply(int source, int factor) {
        return source * factor;
    }
}
```

This class inherits from the following base class:

```
public class CalculatorBase {
    public CalculatorBase(Document document) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("UNAVAILABLE IN UT CONTEXT.");
    }
}
```

NOTE: The constructor does actually a lot of things, which I would like not to do in UT's.
For simplicity, I've made the constructor throw an exception.

Now I want to add an 'Add' function to the Calculator class.
This function looks like:

```
public int Add(int left, int right) {
    return left + right;
}
```

A UT for this particular piece of code should be very straightforward.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Ensure that adding numbers DOES work correctly.")
void addition() throws Exception {
    // ARRANGE.
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator(null);

    // ACT.
    int result = calculator.Add(1, 1);

    // ASSERT.
    Assertions.assertEquals(2, result);
}
```

Since the constructor of the `CalculatorBase` base does throw an exception this unit test will NEVER pass.

The tricky part to make this testable is that the `CalculatorBase` class is auto generated by a tool, thus the source code of that class cannot be modified.

What (baby) steps should I take to make ensure that the `Add` method on the `Calculator` class can be tested? The goal is to make the whole project testable, and even get rid of the auto generated stuff, but I would like to use TDD wherever possible in order to refactor the code gradually.

One could argue that I can make the `Add` method static since it doesn't use any dependencies of the `Calculator` class, but the code is just quickly added together. The `Add` function is, in the actual scenario, something else which does consume the state of the `Calculator` class.

Comment: I believe Test Driven Development as the name implies is a discipline to use to develop software. You can refactor and unit test your code without TDD.

Comment: So how am I able to refactor this, and ensure that I'm not breaking anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Create the new method as static
2. Create a temporal alternative constructor commented as "Only for testing"
3. Refactor the class to remove the dependency
4. Suppress it with [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior)

But the safest way to do it is to create an scaffold test. This build the class even if the constructor has dependencies. You may need to break the encapslation with setters just for testing. Once the class is really well tested you may refactor the class, add better tests and finally remove the dirty scaffold test. Depending on the complexity of the class this may be appropiate or an overkill.

Comment: 1. Let's assume that the `Add` method does use state of the `Calculator` class, so making it `static` would NOT work.

2. The temporary constructor should be added in the `CalculatorBase` class then, but this is auto generated. So as soon as the file is regenerated, the constructor is removed again and the UT's won't compile anymore.

3. Removing the dependencies without tests is fragile. I might introduce bugs that I'm not aware off.

I don't know scaldfold testing. You mind to explain this a bit more?

Comment: A scaffold test is just a temporal test used to refactor the class without introduccing new bugs. (As you said, it is fragile). Just like when you reform an old building. You may prefer the name "Temporal ugly test"

Here are some tecniques: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Z_h55jMe-M#t=1h1m7s

Comment: So more like an integration test in the first phase just in order to be able to make it testable ...

Comment: You may requiere a temporal integration test. Remeber TDD != Unit test

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new **protected** or **package-private** static method `add` with an extra `Calculator` parameter (at least for now, until the class can be easily instantiated), and create your test using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito):

```
class Calculator extends CalculatorBase {

    private final int limit = 100; // to show that we need an instance state in add method 

    ....

    public int add(int left, int right) {
        return add(this, left, right);
    }

    static int add (Calculator calculator, int left, int right) {
        return Math.min(left + right, calculator.getLimit());
    }

    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }
}
```

And the test becomes:

```
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Ensure that adding numbers DOES work correctly.")
    void addition() throws Exception {
        // ARRANGE.
        Calculator calculator = Mockito.mock(Calculator.class);

        Mockito.when(calculator.getLimit()).thenReturn(100);

        // ACT.
        int result = Calculator.add(calculator, 1, 1);

        // ASSERT.
        Assertions.assertEquals(3, result);
    }
```

But in this case, I prefer to create a new Class called `ArithmeticCalculator` with a simple constructor and use it inside the `Calculator` class (Aka [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)), then redirect the arithmetic operations to it, so it will help for a better testing and it may promote a [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).